# Multiple tabs in xcode

Tags: xcode, window

Is there a way to open up multiple files that are not apart of a project, into one single tabbed window in xcode?

My situation is that I am using xcode as an editor for my C files and the number of windows open is getting out of hand. I prefer not to have to create a project and have all the extra files in project folder.

I have tried to figure this out before asking on here but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 4 only enables you to have tabs of the same project within one window, as the workspace setting is part of the project settings.
If you like to use Xcode as an editor for your C-files, maybe creating a dummy project and including all the C-files may suit your needs ... or you switch to an other popular editor like TextMate.